# Can't install mblock. Error Pango

Tags: pango

I am trying to install mblock. I have created a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -O mblock.tar.gz https://github.com/Makeblock-official/mBlock/releases/download/V4.0.0-Linux/mBlock-4.0.0-linux-4.0.0.tar.gz
tar zxvf mblock.tar.gz
mv mBlock $HOME
cd $HOME
cd mBlock
./mblock
```

The following error message appears:

**(mblock:65449): Pango-ERROR : 10:45:57.367: Harfbuzz version too old (1.2.7)**

Thanks in advance!!

My ubuntu version is the following one:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"  
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"  
ID=ubuntu  
ID_LIKE=debian  
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"  
VERSION_ID="20.04"  
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"  
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"  
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"  
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"  
VERSION_CODENAME=focal  
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

I have tried installing using debian packages:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -O mblock.deb http://mblockapp.oss-cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/mBlock4.0/mBlock_4.0.4_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mblock.deb
```

Using debian packages the following message appears:

[image]

and with **dmesg** appears:

```
kern  :warn  : [  +4,352967] process 'opt/makeblock/mBlock/mblock' started with executable stack
kern  :info  : [  +0,829370] traps: mblock[3364] trap int3 ip:7fab7e5e5295 sp:7ffe5dba1020 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.6400.6[7fab7e5a9000+84000]
kern  :info  : [feb18 17:54] traps: mblock[5485] trap int3 ip:7f0d85978295 sp:7ffc36c9ff40 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.6400.6[7f0d8593c000+84000]
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @NOrbert, I have added the ubuntu version to my ask question. Thanks

Comment: FYI it works on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but really fails on 20.04 LTS. I have reported an issue to https://github.com/Makeblock-official/mBlock/issues/93 .

Comment: Thank you so much @NOrbert